# Strange Gradle IntelliJ error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

When I try to import a Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA, I get the following error:

[image]

The IDE log starts out as follows:

```
[1314928]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - 
 (of class java.lang.String) 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: 
 (of class java.lang.String)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:358)
```

#### Versions:

- IntelliJ 13.1.4
- Gradle 1.12
- Ubuntu 14.04

#### Minimal example:

If I try to create a new project, I get:

```
Error:Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3-sources.jar
 (of class java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Can you provide any more detail?  Gradle / IntelliJ versions?  Does this occur for *any* Gradle project?  If it's a specific one, can you create a minimal test-case?

Comment: Are you sure, you're well connected to the internet?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Yep, builds without problem on the command line.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm experiencing same symptoms.

[java8-gradle-tests](master)$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-07-01 07:45:34 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b6ead6fa452dfdadec484059191eb641d817226c

Groovy:       2.3.3
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9.3 x86_64

IntelliJ is 13.1.4 Ultimate

Comment: This happened to me as well, after installing the most recent scala plugin update (version 0.41) for IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @jan I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Scenario**

- Error message encountered on IntelliJ 13.1.4 on OS X 10.9.4, using Gradle 1.11.
- Project previously worked fine in IntelliJ 13.1.3, but now the Gradle
  import fails since IntelliJ 13.1.4.

**Resolution**

This is resolved by disabling the Scala plugin as per http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7405

---

*Further update:*

The Jetbrains issue commentary suggests that this issue with the Scala plugin is now resolved in the latest plugin version, which has now been released.

Comment: updating scala plugin to the latest version fixed problem, thanks